# Access to reference in member variable discards constness

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, compiler-errors, constants

I made a wrapper around an object in my code that should modify accesses to the object. I choose to use an object here for testing instead of a functor that would have the same functionality.  Basically: The wrapper receives a reference to the object and forwards all indexed accesses to the object (after some possible manipulation)
Now comes the problem: The accessor discards constness of the wrapped object. 
Minimal Example

```
struct Foo
{
    std::array<int, 2> data;
    const int& operator()(int idx) const{
        return data[idx];
    }
    int& operator()(int idx){
        return data[idx];
    }
};

struct Bar
{
    Foo& ref;
    Bar(Foo& r):ref(r){}
    int& operator()(int idx) const{
        return ref(idx);
    }
};

template< typename T >
void test(const T& data){
    data(1) = 4;
    std::cout << data(1);
}

void main(){
    Foo f;
    test(f);
    // Above call does not compile (as expected)
    // (assignment of read-only location)
    Bar b(f);
    test(b); // This does compile and works (data is modified)
}
```

Declaring the ()-operator of Bar (the wrapper) "const", I'd expect to be all member accesses "const" to. So it shouldn't be possible to return an "int&" but only a "const int&"

However gcc4.7 happily compiles the code and the const is ignored. Is this the correct behavior? Where is this specified?

Edit:
On a related issue: If use typedefs in Foo like:

```
struct Foo
{
    using Ref = int&;
    using ConstRef = const int&; //1
    using ConstRef = const Ref;  //2
    int* data; // Use int* to have same issue as with refs
    ConstRef operator()(int idx) const{
        return data[idx]; // This is possible due to the same "bug" as with the ref in Bar
    }
    Ref operator()(int idx){
        return data[idx];
    }
};
```

I noticed that //1 does work as expected but //2 does not. Return value is still modifiable. Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: It is the correct behavior. I won't make this an answer since I don't want to bother looking up a quote from the standard, but basically your member variable is the reference itself, not the int being referred to.
So in your operator() const, the reference member "ref" is not modified, only the Foo it refers too.

I think C++17 will have const propagating pointer and references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is correct behaviour. The type of `ref` is `Foo &`. Adding `const` to a reference type<sup>1</sup> does nothing—a reference is already immutable, anyway. It's like having a member `int *p`. In a `const` member function, its type is treated as `int * const p`, not as `int const * p`.

What you need to do is add `const` manually inside the `const` overload if you want it there:

```
struct Bar
{
    Foo& ref;
    Bar(Foo& r):ref(r){}
    int& operator()(int idx) const{
        return const_cast<const Foo&>(ref)(idx);
    }
};
```

To address the question edit: no, the typedefs are not the same. `const int &` is a reference to a (constant `int`). `const Ref` is a constant `Ref`, that is, a constant (reference to `int`); parentheses used in mathematical sense.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am talking about the reference type itself. Not to be confused with adding `const` to the type to which the reference refers.

Comment: "Adding const to a reference type does nothing" --- what do you mean? `const int&` and `int&` are different, aren't they?

Comment: @Petr `const int&` is a reference to a `const int`, which is different from a `const` reference to an `int`.

Comment: @TartanLlama, ok, I think I understand what the author meant, but I think that that sentence as written now is anyway misleading...

Comment: @Petr That's adding `const` to the type to which the reference refers, to the type of the reference. I will re-word the answer slightly.

Comment: So basicly if I had a "Foo& ref" and "Foo inst" in Bar, then inside the const function it would be like "Foo& const ref" and "Foo const inst" (="const Foo inst") right?

Comment: @Flamefire Yes; with the technicality that `Foo & const ref` is in reality syntactic nonsense. How this really works: all accesses to members are treated as if done through `this->`, and in `const` member functions, `this` is of type `const T*`.

Comment: Alright. I added an edit to the question that seems related. Do you also know something about the difference of these typedefs? (BTW: Foo& const ref is perfectly acceptable for the compiler, although its (semantic) nonsense, so I'd rather say its duplicate)

Comment: @Flamefire It shouldn't be accepted. C++11 8.3.2/1: "Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced
through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument (14.3), in which case the cv-qualifiers
are ignored."

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is expected behaviour. The reason is that const for your method says only that reference wont be change not the referenced object. Reference is always unchanged so it is always true. Take a look at this code with pointer:

```
int i;
struct Bar
{
    int* pi;
    Foo& ref;
    Bar(Foo& r):ref(r){}
    int& operator()(int idx) const{
        *pi = 4; // we can change pointed object
        pi = &i; // Compile error: we can't change the pointer.
        return ref(idx);
    }
};
```